# Gridview ButtonField Click not working

Tags: c#, gridview

So I have a gridview being populated from SQL stored procedure.  Everything is populating fine.  I have a button field that I have added where, when clicked, will just display a hidden label.  I want it to do something else but this is a test so I can see if I am getting the right row.

```
protected void ServiceList_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "ServiceRestart")
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        GridViewRow selectedRow = ServiceList.Rows[index];
        TableCell serviceName = selectedRow.Cells[1];
        string service = serviceName.Text;

        Label1.Visible = true;
        Label1.Text = service;
    }
}
```

Here is the code on the gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="ServiceList" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px" OnRowCommand="ServiceList_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ServerName" HeaderText="Server Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ServerIP" Visible="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DisplayName" HeaderText="Service Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" />
        <asp:ButtonField HeaderText="Restart" Text="Restart" ButtonType="Link" CommandName="ServicResStart" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

When I click the link, nothing happens.

EDIT: And I guess another question would be, if the gridview is being populated from SQL, how does the click event know which row is being clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got this working if anyone is running into the same issue.  Basically combined the two lines into the new serviceName line.

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
GridViewRow selectedRow = ServiceList.Rows[index];
var serviceName = selectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
```